# Compilation flag to handle long path/filename in I/O operations in Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio-2015, io, compilation

There's currently a limit to the length of the input file/directory that the Visual Studio I/O operations can handle (not sure if its 180 or 260 or something similar).
I understood that there's a possible compilation flag (hopefully supported in VS2015) which can help with this issue and increase the max acceptable length for input.

Would appreciate your help in identifying the right flag.

Not sure if 32bit vs 64bit compilation has any effect here as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

> Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative
>   Templates -> System -> Filesystem -> Set "Enable Win32 long paths" to
>   Enabled

Also:

> Starting in Windows 10, version 1607, MAX_PATH limitations have been removed from common Win32 file and directory functions. However, you must opt-in to the new behavior.

[read more here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file)

Comment: Thank you for the response. So this is something that needs to be changed/enabled on the PC itself. Since what I'm working on is expected to run on many PCs, is there some option within VS for this project?

Comment: @just_a_user not sure; you may code your application such that it access and modifies the relevant registry entries. not sure if this is advised though